# how to change date format in json

Tags: java, json

How can I replace data format in json?
For example, I have json object like this

```
{
"dt1":"12-12-2020",
"street":"test",
"city":"test2",
"country":"test3",
"dt2":"12-11-2020"
}
```

as result I want to get

```
{
"dt1":"12/12/2020",
"street":"test",
"city":"test2",
"country":"test3",
"dt2":"12/11/2020"
}
```

I have different names of field, so we don't need to depend on name of field just need to  replace data format...
How can I do that???

Comment: How are you creating `JSON`? Share sample code.

Comment: It's like input parameter

Comment: Share the sample code.

Comment: I don't have any code

Comment: Just so I'm clear, this isn't json that you're generating, but json that you're receiving from some external source?

Comment: yes, you're right

Comment: When you say you "have json object like this", how is it stored in your java program? Is it in a string? a library object like JSONObject? mapped to a pojo using a library like jackson? Or do you not have any starting point yet in Java? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Java 8 or above and the JSON object you have is from the `org.json.JSONObject` package it can be done in the following way:

```
// Example of jsonStr
/* String jsonStr = "{\n"
        + "\"dt1\":\"12-12-2020\",\n"
        + "\"street\":\"test\",\n"
        + "\"city\":\"test2\",\n"
        + "\"country\":\"test3\",\n"
        + "\"dt2\":\"12-11-2020\"\n"
        + "}";
*/
public String converter(String jsonStr) {

  // jsonStr is our original JSON with the date in the dash format (e.g. "12-12-2020")

  // Here we convert into our json object 
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

  // Get the orginal date value
  String dateStr = (String) json.get("dt1");

  // Convert the date into new format and update the JSON key 'dt1' with the new value
  json.put("dt1", dateConverter(dateStr));

  return json.toString();
}

private String dateConverter(String dateStr) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
}
```

*Note 1: The assumption for Java 8  or above is due to the new `LocalDate` object upon date conversion.*

*Note 2: This assumes the date is in the the `dd-MM-yyyy` format as opposed to `MM-dd-yyyy`.*

*Note 3: I would also consider moveing the date conversion to a Utils class.*

Comment: Is it possible not to bind to the field name for updating date format?

Comment: If you don't know the field name, how do you expect to know which field to update?

Comment: One way to do this is to loop through each of the fields finding a value that matches dd-MM-yyyy and replacing that with the required date format. It's not pretty & error prone.

Answer (score 0):

One way I think of is that you can you [Gson](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-parse-json-with-gson/) library to convert the one json format to another format. Its like you convert Json string to Java object using *Gson.fromJson* and then convert back to your required Json string format from Java object using *Gson.toJson*. Let me share sample code that you try :

```
Gson gsonFormat1 = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy").create();
String format1 = "{\n" +
            "\"dt1\":\"12-12-2020\",\n" +
            "\"street\":\"test\",\n" +
            "\"city\":\"test2\",\n" +
            "\"country\":\"test3\",\n" +
            "\"dt2\":\"12-11-2020\"\n" +
            "}";

//Assume Sample is POJO for above json
Sample sampleFormat1 = gsonFormat1.fromJson(format1, Sample.class);
Gson gsonFormat2 = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy").create();

//Your output String here
String s2 = gsonFormat2.toJson(sampleFormat1, Sample.class);
System.out.println("Format2 String => "+s2);
```

Using above technique you don't need to know the any date field names. Basically all the date type fields can be converted to target format. Hope this helps.